# How to properly use .loc with a multilevel index in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this Pandas dataframe with a multilevel index.

[image]

I want to access a particular row of this dataframe so I tried

```
df.loc[(0, 0, '2015-07-01'),:]
```

But it gives a KeyError for `'2015-07-01'`. For any of the combination of the three levels of index, it throws the same error. What's wrong with my line of code?

I don't think the datatype of the date is an issue here, still, it's `object` so accessing it as a string should work.

```
df.index.get_level_values(2)
```

[image]